# Direct connection to domain without router configuration

Tags: networking, internet, raspberry-pi, domain

I'm trying to get a server at home online through a domain but I've stumbled upon a big issue.

Our provider does not allow administrative access to the router, and I'm unable to not only attach the domain to the router, but I'm not even able to enable port forwarding.

Is there a tool I can use to directly open up a connection between the server and the domain (this server does have internet access), or do I really have to do everything behind the NAT router?

I only need to get one server online on three ports (but hopefully be able to configure more), 80 (HTTP), 22 (SSH), and 443 (HTTPS). I'm using a Raspberry Pi 1 B+. I'm trying to get my development server up first before I get my production server online to test things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youb dont need access to the router (in fact it does not generally help you except in the special case of setting up dynamic DNS). You need a static IP address assigned to your router (your ISP would need to do that) and you configure that in the domain names DNS records.

If you can't set up port forwarding you can't set up a connection from servers to your internal network (without an additional layer, below).

If you need to run a server you can find a VPN provider that will allocate a static IP address to you, and then set up the VPN connection on your server (or a secondary router capable of handling it), and then treat that as your IP address. In this way your computer has initiated an outbound connection and incoming packets can use that to get back to your network.